# Usage of ternary operator with return

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

In c++

`size>5?cout<<"size is greater than 5":cout<<"size less than 5";` is working but

`size>5?cout<<"size is greater than 5":return 0;` is throwing compile time

this may be a basic doubt,

what am I  missing from the usage of ternary operator and why the second statement gives compile time error?

Thanks.

Comment: `return 0` is not an expression.

Comment: What do you mean to achieve with "return 0"? Maybe you believe it does something it does not.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It's a basic question, but not iherently a bad one.

Comment: Can you list the compile error?

Comment: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘return'` is the compilation error I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what am I missing from the usage of ternary operator?

Each branch must be an expression. A return statement is not an expression.

If you want to put more general statements in either branch, or if you just want to make the code less nightmarish to read, then use `if...else`.

Comment: Then what about cout<<

Comment: @Sabari, `cout` is an object and `<<` is an operator. `cout << "something"` is much like `a + b`.

Comment: @Sabari: That's an expression, so it can be used here, if you really want to. Even so, `if..else` would be more readable, and will remove the constraint that both branches or the conditional operator must have compatible types.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is an *operator*, which means it's part of an *expression.* Its arguments (operands) are *expressions* as well.

`return 0` is not an expression - it's a statement. What you're doing is somewhat similar to e.g. this:

```
int a = 4 + for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) { std::cout << j; };
```

You need flow control, not just different expressions - use an `if` instead of the ternary operator. That would be a good idea in your first line as well: use the ternary operator sparignly, and definitely not just as a shorthand for `if`.